# PHP Tally of hours is different when cross-checked with Google

Tags: laravel, time, php-carbon

I am calculating the sum of hours using PHP inside Laravel. When I cross check the result in Google, the results are different.

Here is my the code in the controller:

```
$times[] = '7:55';
$times[] = '7:55';
$minutes = 0;

foreach ($times as $time) {
    list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
    $minutes += $hour * 60;
    $minutes += $minute;
}

$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
$minutes -= $hours * 60;

$tally = sprintf('%02d.%02d', $hours, $minutes);
dd($times, $tally);
```

The output is: "15.50";

but in google, the output is "15.1".

In Excel and Google Sheets, the output is also "15.50".

Which one is correct and how can I modify my code to reflect the same result as google.

Comment: You should display: `15:50` (`sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes)`) rather than `15.50` which is a decimal number and would mean `15h 30m`

Answer (score 0):

15.1 is wrong, 15h 50m is correct. Time summing is not a mystery, you can check it manually: 7h 55m for example is 8h - 5m, so the sum of the 2 is 16h - 10m = 15h 50m.